# Returning group maximum and NA using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I need a function I can use that returns both the group maximum and any NA values. Here is toy data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:5, 
                          each = 3),
                 score = rnorm(15))

df$score[c(3,7,10,14)] <- NA

#    id      score
# 1   1 -1.4666164
# 2   1  0.4392647
# 3   1         NA
# 4   2 -0.6010311
# 5   2  1.9845774
# 6   2  0.1749082
# 7   3         NA
# 8   3 -0.3089731
# 9   3  0.4427471
# 10  4         NA
# 11  4  1.7156319
# 12  4 -0.2354253
# 13  5  1.1781350
# 14  5         NA
# 15  5  0.0642082
```

I can use `slice_max` to get the maximum in each group:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
    slice_max(score)

#      id score
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1     1 0.439
# 2     2 1.98 
# 3     3 0.443
# 4     4 1.72 
# 5     5 1.18
```

But how do I get the maximum *plus* any NAs returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `group_by` the `id` column, then use `summarize` to output the summaries with `max`. Here, two `max` are used, with one of them has `na.rm = T` and the other doesn't. `union()` is used to combine output that is present in both `max`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(score = union(max(score, na.rm = T), max(score)))
```

**UPDATE: The above code only works if you have at most one `NA` per ID. Thanks @KU99 for the reminder.**

If you have more than one `NA` per ID, you need to combine the result of `max` with the records of `NA` found by `is.na()`.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(score = c(max(score, na.rm = T), score[is.na(score)]))
```

#### Result

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
# Groups:   id [5]
     id  score
  <int>  <dbl>
1     1  0.735
2     1 NA    
3     2  0.314
4     3  0.994
5     3 NA    
6     4  0.847
7     4 NA    
8     5  1.95 
9     5 NA
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), score = c(-1.05089006245306, 0.734652105895187, 
NA, -1.31427279695036, -0.250038722057874, 0.314204596436828, 
NA, 0.994420599790523, 0.855768431757766, NA, 0.834325037545013, 
0.846790152407738, 1.95410525460771, NA, 0.971120269710021)), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it if there are more than one NA, it will only give one instead of all of them

Comment: @KU99 Thanks for the reminder! Updated the code to include this rule!

Comment: do `score[is.na(score)]` be careful of using `which` for index

Comment: In this case, its redundant. Generally its not a good idea because it can lead to wrong values when doing the negation. Use the logical vector insted. eg `x <- 1:5` `x[x>3]` will be the same as `x[which(x>3)]`  and  `x[is.na(x)]` will be the same as `x[which(is.na(x))]` but `x[!is.na(x)]` is not the same as `x[-which(is.na(x))]` and using `which` here produces wrong results Hope this helps

Comment: @KU99 Thanks so much for the explanation, I've learnt a lot from you in SO!

Comment: If you are using `which` make sure that you ALWAYS use it in a positive sense. ie get the indices needed

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use `slice` and `|` to create a logical condition with `is.na` to return the `NA` rows and the `max` rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  slice(which(score == max(score, na.rm = T)|is.na(score)))
```

Another option would be to use `slice.max` as you did but then to use `bind_rows` to add the `NA` values back to the dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice_max(score) %>% 
  bind_rows(df %>% filter(is.na(score))) %>% 
  arrange(id)
```

**Output**

```
     id   score
  <int>   <dbl>
1     1 -0.161 
2     1 NA     
3     2  1.49  
4     3 -0.451 
5     3 NA     
6     4  0.878 
7     4 NA     
8     5 -0.0652
9     5 NA
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), score = c(-0.161217942983375, -0.456571996252207, 
NA, 0.540071362460494, 1.49325799630099, -0.17985218510166, NA, 
-0.451301758592, -0.839100876399644, NA, -0.0432130218441599, 
0.87779273806634, -0.339260854059069, NA, -0.065177224102029)), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a custom function you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

slice_max_na <- function(.data, order_by, ..., n, prop, with_ties = TRUE) {
  bind_rows(
    slice_max(.data, order_by = {{order_by}}, ..., n = n, prop = prop, with_ties = with_ties),
    filter(.data, is.na({{order_by}})),
  )
}

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice_max_na(score)
#> # A tibble: 9 × 2
#> # Groups:   id [5]
#>      id  score
#>   <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     1 -0.230
#> 2     2  1.72 
#> 3     3 -0.687
#> 4     4  1.22 
#> 5     5  0.401
#> 6     1 NA    
#> 7     3 NA    
#> 8     4 NA    
#> 9     5 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is `dplyr` version more using `rank`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(rank = rank(-score, ties.method = "random")) %>% 
  filter(rank == 1 | is.na(score)) %>% 
  select(-rank)
```

```
     id  score
  <int>  <dbl>
1     1  0.505
2     1 NA    
3     2 -0.109
4     3 NA    
5     3  1.45 
6     4 NA    
7     4  0.355
8     5 NA    
9     5 -0.298
```